# Is there a JSON schema for Add-On manifest files?

Tags: add-on

I see we have a [Gateway article](https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/en_US/ReferenceArticle/000012048?articleName=000015377) for example configuration, [documentation for the manifest.json](https://docs.rws.com/986894/545624/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/structure-of-the-manifest-file-of-the-add-on) file for Add-On packages, and [good examples by @vantonenko on GitHub](https://github.com/vantonenko/TridionExtensionTemplates).

But is there a JSON schema of sorts or list of the manifest options, specifically for properties like `EXTENSIONTYPE` and `EXTENSIONVERSION`. Also, do paths use forward ("/") or back ("\") slash?

Ideally, it'd be nice to be able to create and edit the Add-On manifest.json file with auto-completing intellisense, but a list of valid options would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a Community wiki to gather examples and known details. Feel free to add to this or add an answer if there is a Schema for the manifest file format for Add-ons.

### Type

The list of type options are documented under [Extension Types](https://docs.rws.com/986894/545688/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/extension-types) and includes, as of Tridion Sites 9.6:

- CMApplicationDataConfiguration
- Connector
- CDDeployerExtension
- CDModelTransformerExtension
- CMResolver
- ECLProvider
- CMEventHandler
- UIEditor
- UIModel
- CDGraphQLSchemaExtension
- CDMergeableConfigurationExtension
- CMApplicationDataConfiguration

### Use "\" for local paths

In the Application Data Configuration Extension documentation you can see a file referenced using double back slash:

```
{
  "name":"MyAppDataConfigurationExtension",
  "type": "CMApplicationDataConfiguration",
  "properties": {
    "xmlFileName": "CM\\MyCustomAppDataConfig.xml"
  }
}
```

The `MyCustomAppDataConfig.xml` app data configuration file is placed in a folder named "CM" in the Add-on ZIP file.

### Yet Another Example

Here's the [manifest file format per the documentation](https://docs.rws.com/986894/707998/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/basic-structure-of-the-add-on-manifest-file).

```
{
  "manifestVersion": "MANIFESTVERSION",
  "version": "ADDONVERSION",
  "id": "ADDONIDENTIFIER"
  "name": "ADDONFEATURENAME",
  "requireConfiguration": "CONFIGREQUIREMENT",
  "author": "AUTHORNAME",
  "description": "DESCRIPTION",
  "icon": "ICONIMAGEFILE",
  "extensions": [
    EXTENSION1,
    EXTENSION2,
    ...
  ]
}
```

Here's an example from demos and training.

```
{
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "id": "SchemaRenamer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "SchemaRenamer",
  "description": "Event System Extension",
  "icon": "Renamer.png",
  "author": "Demo User",
  "requireConfiguration": "Yes",
  "extensions": [
    {
      "name": "TCMExtension",  
      "type": "CMEventHandler",
      "properties": {
            "assemblyFileSource": "EventSystemExtension.dll"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```